# Problemas para imprimir una lista

Tags: python

Hola amigos de Stack Over FLow, tengo el siguiente código, con el white genero una lista, y con el for agrego nuevos elementos a esa lista, ¿Por que el ultimo print no me imprime esa nueva lista con los nuevos elementos?

Me salen elementos infinitos

```
nueva_lista =[]

numero_lista = int(input('ingresar numero:      '))

i = 1

while i <= int(numero_lista):

    nueva_lista.append(i)

    i += 1

print(nueva_lista)

#nueva_entrada = int(input('ingresar numero:      '))   

#numero_siguiente = nueva_entrada + 1

#nueva_lista.append(numero_siguiente)

#print(nueva_lista)

for x in nueva_lista:

    print(x + numero_lista)

#   if x <= len(nueva_lista):

#       y = x + numero_lista

    nueva_lista.append(x + numero_lista)

print(nueva_lista)
```

¿Alguien sabe a que se deba?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿qué contenido esperas que tenga la `nueva_lista` cuando la imprimas?

Comment: Por ejemplo en el input yo ingreso el numero 3, el white me genera una lista con los elementos 1,2,3 lo que busco con el for es sumarle otros tres números que les falta, como ingrese 3 debería ser 4,5,6 y con el append lo agrego a la lista, pero con el ultimo print no me imprime esa lista con los nuevos números añadidos.

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de la salida esperada y la salida obtenida, para poder apreciar las diferencias y validar el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en el bucle FOR:

```
for x in nueva_lista:

    print(x + numero_lista)

    nueva_lista.append(x + numero_lista)
```

Has creado un bucle infinito, porque estás haciendo un loop dentro de cada elemento de `nueva_lista`. Y en cada iteración añades un elemento, así que nunca termina de llegar al final de la lista.

La solución es establecer una relación matemática entre x y número lista. Además puedes resumir tu código con las *list comprehension*

```
numero_lista = int(input('ingresar numero:      '))

nueva_lista = list(range(1,numero_lista+1))

print(nueva_lista) #aquí lista con los primeros valores.

[nueva_lista.append(x + numero_lista) for x in range(1,numero_lista+1)]

print(nueva_lista) # aquí después de añadir segunda tanda valores
```

Algunos output:

```
ingresar numero:      3
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

ingresar numero:      10
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

ingresar numero:      7
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

**NOTA:** Acabo de darme cuenta que tu código en tu bucle for muestras con un print el número que quieres añadir, además de luego añadirlo a la lista. En ese caso mi solución no serviría porque solo hace la adición, saltándose el mostrar los números en pantalla.

Si ese paso es imprescindible, algo así te sirve:

```
numero_lista = int(input('ingresar numero:      '))

nueva_lista = list(range(1,numero_lista+1))

print(nueva_lista) #aquí lista con los primeros valores.

def ampliar(milista,a,b,):
    milista.append(a + b)
    print((a + b))

[ampliar(nueva_lista, x, numero_lista) for x in range(1,numero_lista+1)]

print(nueva_lista) # aquí después de añadir segunda tanda valores
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

nueva_lista =[]

numero_lista = int(input('ingresar numero:      '))

i = 1
```

numero_lista ya es un entero así que el int es redundante
while i <= int(numero_lista):

```
while i <= numero_lista:
    nueva_lista.append(i)

    i += 1

print(nueva_lista)
```

es necesario leer una copia de la lista sino se va incrementando y no termina
por eso uso la función copy

```
for x in nueva_lista.copy():

    print(x + numero_lista)

#   if x <= len(nueva_lista):

#       y = x + numero_lista

    nueva_lista.append(x + numero_lista)

print(nueva_lista)
```